# Unity sometimes blue and ugly

Tags: unity, fonts, gui, menu

Sometimes when I boot and log in into Ubuntu Unity looks ... different and not nice.

The right click menu selections are colored in dark blue and not orange and the menus are not integrating properly with the top bar. I also think some of the fonts are sometimes different.

Here are screenshots of Inkscape demonstrating my problem.

[image: Unity NOT working peoperly]
Not working properly

[image: Unity working properly]
Working properly

If I log out and then log in the problem is fixed but what can I do to fix it permenently? I is really annoying.

Thanks.

Comment: This is a known bug that I encountered rather frequently on 14.04,  and related to gnome-setting-daemon. Is it still present on 16.04? See this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/649809)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to barotto I found out that this bug has been in Ubuntu for some years but it is very rare in newer versions. (There has been only one report on 16.04 )

**I installed Ubuntu 16.10 and that fixed the bug.**